# Trying to find a sql query for finding the max of a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

The offences table has information about crimes committed. I am trying to get which financial quarter(1,2,3,4) had the most number of crimes committed.

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences) FROM offences WHERE financialquarter_ID = 1;
```

this query outputs 4160

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences) FROM offences WHERE financialquarter_ID = 2;
```

This query outputs 4227

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences) FROM offences WHERE financialquarter_ID = 3;
```

This query outputs 4647

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences) FROM offences WHERE financialquarter_ID = 4;
```

This query outputs 4665

So, we can see the quarter 4 has the highest number of crime. I am trying to get a query to output id of this financialquarter_ID (Quarter 4).

So far I have tried following query with no success.

```
select yt.financialquarter_ID, yt.numberOfOffences
From offences yt
where numberOfOffences = 
(select max(numberOfOffences) from offences st where yt.financialquarter_ID = st.financialquarter_ID)
GROUP by numberOfOffences DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the table. 
[image: This is my table offences]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences)
FROM offences
GROUP BY financialquarter_ID
ORDER BY SUM(numberOfOffences) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  In the event of ties, this returns only one row.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT financialquarter_ID, SUM(numberOfOffences) FROM offences group by 
financialquarter_ID
having SUM(numberOfOffences)=(SELECT count(*) FROM offences group by 
financialquarter_ID order by 
count(*) desc limit 1
);
```